# Tyep error : operator || (OR) not compatible error. Is this right way to check the OR condition?

Tags: addresses, operator

[image]

Please help in correcting above error in below code:
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external payable override {
require(zombieTOOwner[_tokenId]= msg.sender || zombieApprovals[_tokenId]= msg.sender);
_transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId);
}

Comment: `=` assigns, `==` checks for equality ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the require statement, you are assigning values, not checking conditions, you will need an `=`more:

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) 
    external payable override { 
    require(zombieTOOwner[_tokenId]== msg.sender || zombieApprovals[_tokenId]== msg.sender); 
    _transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId)
; }
```

Hope it helps